# Function to delete post from category older than 2 days

Tags: posts, wp-delete-post

I was referring to [What would be a PHP command to erase all posts from category X from the last month?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263953/what-would-be-a-php-command-to-erase-all-posts-from-category-x-from-the-last-mon) from 2017 to delete old post from a category.

When I implemented it, it is deleting newest 1 day posts.

```php
//* If the scheduled event got removed from the cron schedule, re-add it if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wpse_amazon_2days' ) ) {   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wpse_amazon_2days' ); }

//* Add action to hook fired by cron event add_action( 'wpse_amazon_2days', 'wpse_amazon_2days' ); function wpse_amazon_2days() {   //* Get all posts older than 7 days...   $posts = get_posts( [
    'cat' => '28153',
    'date_query' => [
      'after' => date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-2 days', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ),
    ],   ]);   //* ...and delete them   foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    wp_delete_post( $post->ID );   } }
```

I want to delete post from category, older than 2 days.

Today: Aug 9th

Delete post from Aug 7 to end of time.

Comment: think of "after" as in "all posts after 2 days ago", aka _newer than_, which is the opposite of what you wanted. Also the code in your question has broken formatting, I tried to fix it and put it in a code block rather than a quote, but you've got multiple lines of code merged onto single lines that are then commented out, multiple closing brackets on the same line etc, it's very difficult to read. Can you reformat it? Use the edit link to adjust it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_posts()` call is retrieving posts that were published after two days earlier. The `after` parameter retrieves posts *after* a certain date, and `strtotime()` is retrieving the date from two days ago.

Try changing `after` to `before`, and then change `strtotime()` first parameter to reflect your request. Researching the `get_posts()` and `strtotime()` functions will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you keeping the query as is, but changing the after to before made the trick.

Comment: @apptikka if this answered your question consider clicking the checkmark under the voting controls to mark it as accepted and award Caleb the points